Why does Pycharm's typechecker think returning a value with the getter returns a ndarray?
I am working on a project, and for one part of it I have to generate some random number arrays, and use each value for a simulation. At first I generate a numpy array of ints / floats and then I extract them in the loop and pass them to my object that handles the rest. At first I only generated 1 value each loop, so I had no problems, but when I moved it outside of the loop and started getting a value from it using [], it started warning me that it Expected type 'int', got 'ndarray[Any, dtype]' instead, suggesting it thinks my_array[i] returns an array instead of a value. This isn't related to numpy.random, as it also happens when creating an array. Working example:
import numpy as np

foo = np.array([0, 1, 2])
bar: int = foo[1]

print(type(bar), bar)

output: <class 'numpy.int64'> 1
This can be solved by adding tolist() after creating the array, though this may not always be what you want and I think it forgoes some typechecking when you do that. Is this a problem with the typechecker, or is there a reason for this behaviour? I am using python 3.10.12 and Pycharm 2024.2.2.

Please post the non-working code so we can tell you what you're doing wrong.

numpy.int64 is the expected type when indexing an array with that dtype.  For most users that isn't a problem. item or tolist can remove that extra numpy layer, but unless you insist on some strict type checking it shouldn't be necesary.

@Barmar sorry for the late answer, but this is the "non-working" code. The code itself isn't the problem, it is the fact that Pycharms typechecker (linter or mypy or whatever, I am not sure which it is) says that it is actually an array instead of an int

IMO you have to describe the problem in more detail. For example, who defines the data types? If that's you, it would be wise to change the bar type. If not, then all you can do is follow the answer you already got. Or, if the type restrictions are optional, why not remove them?

Is that any good to you,
import numpy as np

foo = np.array([0, 1, 2])
#bar: int = foo[1]
bar: int = int(foo[1])

print(type(bar), bar)

output:
<class 'int'> 1

I guess it is "useful" (I considered it myself too), and because I know what is going on I know that this will not cause problems, but I wondered if it was me getting the values from the array in a wrong manner or something. If that is not the case I feel this is indeed the best "solution", but I'm not happy about it. Maybe I need to make an issue in the Pycharm forum / Numpy forum (whichever causes this problem) so they can solve it instead.
